# What chart I should use to draw this relationship?

Tags: chart-type, pedigree

I have a case of a family having a complex relation. I looked at some pedigree templates to draw this, but I can't.

1. Husband was married to Wife who passed away after three years of marriage.
2. They have a child.
3. Now the husband marries the sister of the previous wife.
4. They have a child.

What type of graph/tree I should use to draw this relation? Should I not use pedigree because they can show ancestors and descendants only?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what aspect of the family relationships you want to hightlight. If it's that the two women were sisters, changing the Father & Mother into parents of the wives would be a simple change. Otherwise, you'll have to be more explicit.

Comment: The **Father** and **Mother** are the parents of **Husband**, not wives. Is there a readily-available template that available to draw these types of relationships or should I make a custom drawing for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in most diagrams, the keys are the labels and the connections. Sometimes shapes are evocative of the concepts they contain, but that's creative choice.

If you are wanting to highlight the relationship of the wives, then

- a text-based example

```
    Wives' Father === Wives' Mother
                   |
  _________________|_____________________
  |                                      |
  Wife 1 ========== Husband ========== Wife 2
[deceased]    |                  |    [living]
              |                  |
            Child 1            Child 2
```

- a graphic example based on your image

[image: Sisters as wives 1 & 2]]

Hopefully, this is what you are trying to visualize.